# SQL Query date by adding number of days from same table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have this table:

```
ID DateBegin  DaysCount
1  2018-03-03 5
```

I need to pass date as parameter to query and find out if passed date is in interval from `2018-03-03` and `2018-03-08` as there is 5 `DaysCount`.

Can you help make it into a query?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
select (case when exists (select 1
                          from t
                          where @date >= t.startdate and
                                @date < dateadd(day, 1 + dayscount, startdate)
                         )
             then 1 else 0
         end) as exists_in_table;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. dateadd function is failing for me with following error Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: @mikola it looks like one or more rows in your table has a malformed date in _DateBegin_. You can search for the culprit using [ISDATE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isdate-transact-sql), like `SELECT * FROM t WHERE ISDATE(DateBegin) = 0`

Comment: @mikola . . . Dates should be stored using `date`, `datetime` or related types.  Strings are for strings, not dates.